# Loop para impressão por página

Tags: php, css

Tenho um loop:

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<=20; $i++){ ?>
<div id="">
   <?php echo $i; ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Preciso que cada uma destas DIVs apareçam de forma separada na hora de imprimir, ou seja, um item por página, independente do height da div, gostaria que fosse apenas uma div por página, como eu poderia fazer isso? Vou em imprimir / imprimir em PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No local que você deseja quebrar a página, coloque esse comando:

```
<div style="page-break-after: always"></div>
```

Irá quebrar para a página seguinte.